# Assigning conditional global liquid variables in Shopify

Tags: ruby, shopify, liquid

I'm using trying to display shopify content based on the local domain it's using. To do this I've got the below which works fine:

```
{% if request.host contains 'co.nz' %}
  {% assign site_currency = "NZ" %}
{% endif %}
```

The problem is that variables seem to only work within the one snippet/template/layout file prior to being compiled, and what Shopify classes as a global variable is in fact just a value from the theme settings and therefore can't be conditional.

I've tried '{% assign scope = ‘page’ %}' which apparently works after compilation but I can't get it to work and there's very little documentation.

Does anyone know how I can declare this variable just once and then reference it throughout my theme?

Thanks!

Comment: In theory, if you add the above code in a snippet and `render` it in `theme.liquid` before `{{ content_for_layout }}` this variable should be available in all pages except checkout.

Comment: Actually `render` won't work, instead use `include`, what's funny is that `include` is [deprecated](https://shopify.dev/changelog/deprecating-the-include-liquid-tag-and-introducing-the-render-tag), so it might stop working in the near future.

Comment: @KarimTarek .. include also doesn't work unless you use it `with`. In which case, render also works,

Comment: @HymnZ I tried the code I posted in my answer and `include` worked without `with` :)

Comment: Does it work inside `content_for_layout` and other snippets by directly referencing `{{ site_currency }}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify global variables are only the objects specified here - https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects

Only way to acheieve a global reference functionality without referencing through snippets is by storing it in the `cart.attributes` via JS, but that requires a page refresh to take effect.

Comment: Frustrating but thanks for the info, at least you saved me from a dead end of problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

Create a snippet or just paste the code above `{{ content_for_layout }}` in `theme.liquid`

```
{% comment %} /snippets/global-vars.liquid {% endcomment %}

{% if request.host contains 'co.nz' %}
  {% assign site_currency = "NZ" %}
{% endif %}
```

*If you have few different currencies I suggest that you look into using `case/when`, [here are](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/control-flow-tags#case-when) the docs.*

```
{% comment %} /layout/theme.liquid {% endcomment %}

...

{% include 'global-vars' %}
{% comment %} this should print the currency {% endcomment %}
{{ site_currency }} 
{{ content_for_layout }}

...
```